# time variable in split experiment in lme function

Tags: r, lme4, nlme

I am carrying out an split experiment with microbiology.
Totally 3 blocks I set: A,B,C;
each block contains 2 incobators, with setting temperature at 19 and 31 °c, respectively.
In each incubator, 2 replicated microganism sample are cultured (a,b).

now I want to compare density of microganism between generation 27 (which I got and stocked a years agao) and 2400 (which I got and stocked now). [split experiment diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7LOD.png)

[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueqOp.png)

I write this code, it works

```
modele.ed <- lme ( density ~ temperature*generation, random = ~1|block/temperature/generation, na.action = na.omit, data = datae)
```

but it looks like wrong. I still dont know how to deal with "generation".what is the right code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first reaction is to remove 'generation' (because I don't think it's nested inside each experiment) from the nested random effects, it should probably be 'replicate' in there, thus:

```
modele.ed <- lme ( density ~ temperature*generation, random = ~1|block/temperature/replicate, na.action = na.omit, data = datae)
```

Whether or not there is enough levels for that nested random effect to work is another question. To check the validity of your experimental design, you would do better to post on http://stats.stackexchange.com (for stats) as opposed to here which is mainly for code.

Also consider using `library(lme4)` and its `lmer()` functions as it is more popular and easier to make formulae for.

Comment: I meant http://stats.stackexchange.com Cross Validated